# Make web page recognize hover continuation to next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to make it so that, when a visitor clicks on a navigation tab, and the slider moves, the slider should stay in the same position since there mouse is still on it from the previous page. By same position on hover, I mean when it moves all the way to the left.

Demo (Use Assignments page and Dream Cars page): [Demo](http://travisingram.net/sof/Web%20Design/)

Apologies for the additional subfolders, I am in a rush and don't have time to bother with the space in web design, since centos wont pick it up...

JSFiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/EdLVx/ (Doubt it will though).

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
<div id="navlinks">
<nav>
<ul id="navlist">
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="assignments.html">ASSIGNMENTS</a></li>
<li><a href="cars.html">DREAM CARS</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar{
width:100%;
height:50px;
display:table;
margin:auto;
}
#navlinks ul {
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%;
margin:0 0 20px;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}
#navlinks li {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
width:25%;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #111 50%, #444 50%);
background-size: 200% 100%;
background-position:left top;
transition:all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition-delay:all 1s ease;
-moz-transition-delay:all 1s ease;
-ms-transition-delay:all 1s ease;
-o-transition-delay:all 1s ease;
}
#navlinks li:hover{
background-position:right top;
}
#navlinks a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #999;
text-transform: uppercase;
display:block;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
transition:all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition-delay:all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition-delay:all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition-delay:all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition-delay:all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#navlinks a:hover{
color:black;
}
#navlinks a:active{
color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you add an active class on the a tag when you are on that active page.
You cancel the transition for the active nav item.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tauA3/9/show/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/tauA3/9/

```
#navlinks a.active{
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: all 0 ease-in;
    transition: none;
    background:#444;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, if I'm understanding what you want - would be to make an **.active** class:

```
#navlinks li.active{
  background: #444;
}
```

Then for the `li` tag, you would just set `class="active"` on it. This would then give it your grey background.

However, you would need to tweak the **#navlist** sub **li** elements, to remove the **.active** class whenever they hover over another element (otherwise it would remain grey)

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('ul#navlist li a').hover( function() { 
        $('ul#navlist li').each( function() { 
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    } );
} );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EdLVx/4/